# How can I write to the parallel port from the Windows Command line?

Tags: command-line, windows-xp, parallel-port

How can I write to parallel port through Windows XP command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your reply to Zoredache, your real problem is not output to the parallel port, that's trivial.

Your real problem is how to get a 0xff character on stdout.  This is possible with a trivial `.com` executable which invokes the relevant soft interrupt, but to be honest it's probably easier to create a file with that single 0xff character in it and then just `copy` that to the printer:

```
> copy /b data.bin lpt1
```

Note the `/b` flag which tells copy that the file is a binary file.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the DOS days we would frequently use a command like **type filename.txt > lpt1** to print our text files.

Comment: Actually I do not want to print file but I want to write the hex value FF into it so that all the lines become high.